# change routing codeigniter change controller name

Tags: codeigniter

I want to change the route of my controller method from:

```
category/view/97
```

to:

```
anyname/97
```

How can I do this from my routes.php file?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206065/how-to-organize-country-state-city-browsing-in-codeigniter/24206510#24206510

Answer (score 0):

```
$route['anyname/(:num)'] = "category/view/$1";
```

But are you trying to route all/any URI to the category controllers view method?

Comment: What about this "en", it´s supposed to be in the route too
`$route['en/anyname/(:num)'] = "en/category/view/$1";`