# How to remove controller name from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to remove controller name from the URL 
My Controller name  is  = admin

My Current URL is

http:///myaliveidea.com/usermanagement/admin/dashboard

But I want to make my URL like this

http:///myaliveidea.com/usermanagement/dashboard

please help......

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24206065/how-to-organize-country-state-city-browsing-in-codeigniter-url/24206510#24206510.  Also you have three slashes in your URLs.

Comment: You can use route but still that link is available.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a route in config file, so add this.

```
$route['usermanagement'] = 'admin/dashboard';
```

This will route to your dashboard controller in admin folder.